# NetLogo : getting turtles to direct-link if a condition is true

Tags: netlogo, leader-election

I'm trying to implement YOYO leader election algorithm in netlogo
first step in this algorithm is to orient links ( direct link )from the minimum to the maximumbut between neighbors only !
I tried the command

```
   [`ask turtles with [ [ who ] of self < [who] of one-of link-neighbors ] 
        create-direct-to turtle [who] of one-of link-neighbors ]`
```

this creates direct link from min to max ( neighbors ) but also creates a direct link from max to min ( neighbors )
and I don't know what's wrong :(
here's a screenshot , if you notice theres' a [direct link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2gHF.png) from 0 to 2 and also from 2 to 0 and my goal is to have only from 0 to 2

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that every time you do `one-of`, it randomly selects. So you test against a random link-neighbor in the first line, find it's true and then randomly select a link-neighbor to connect to.

```
 [ ask turtles with [ [ who ] of self < [who] of one-of link-neighbors ] 
   create-direct-to turtle [who] of one-of link-neighbors
 ]
```

More generally, this seems an odd way to achieve your goal. To start with, link-neighbors are the turtles that the turtle is already linked to. `link` is the generic name for all link breeds (I think you have created a breed called direct-link).

I am not entirely clear what you mean by minimum and maximum since your code is just from smaller to larger `who` value, regardless of what other `who` values are available. If you want to create a link from every turtle to every turtle with a higher `who` value, here is some code:

```
ask turtles
[ let targets turtles with [who > [who] of myself]
  create-links-to targets
]
```

In general, it is bad practice to use `who` in NetLogo code. `who` is a completely arbitrary identifier that simply tracks the order that turtles are created. If you have turtles that die, then your code may crash because it is referring to a turtle that no longer exists. Or perhaps at some point you will have two breeds of turtles - `who` doesn't care if your turtle is a person or a dog or a factory or...

This may be one of the very few exceptions, but you might want to think about what you are intending `who` to mean. For example, as this is a leadership model, perhaps you could have a variable called 'charisma' and all the links are from turtles with lower values of charisma to higher values of charisma.

Comment: 0


thank you so much for your explanation , my goal is to tranforme undirected link into directed links from each node to the neighbors who has higher who number ( just like screenshot above ) so that's why I created undirected links and then created directed links if you have any suggestion on how to tranforme an undirected link into a directed link from each node to its higher neighbors who number , I would appreciate it thank you for explaning abt one-of

Comment: all I want is to edit the code above in order to link all neighbors and not one of link neighbors( random link ) @JenB

Comment: The code I wrote does exactly what you appear to want - it creates undirected links from all turtles to all turtles with higher `who` values. You don't need to have directed links first. Have you actually tried the code?

Comment: I wanna ask you if you have an idea on reversing a direct link or changing its direction :/ ?

Comment: If you want to change the direction of a link, you need to create a new link (from `end2` to `end1` of the chosen link) and then delete (`die`) the original link.